# What are the practical problems for designing low freq. chokes or EMI filters

Tags: filter

The power line filters like commercial RFI or EMI [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_filter) usually composed of  R L and C passive components and they don't usually work below under kHz frequencies. 
What makes it difficult or a challenge to design such filter with 200 Hz cut off for instance?

Comment: Hm, you deliver the keywords to this question yourself! So, can you add e.g. an LC low pass filter's circuit diagram, and give a formula for its capacity and inductance given said cutoff frequency? Can you see a problem?

Comment: My conclusion is we need much bigger values for L and C but I dont understand why cannot be constructed even though the filter might be bulky. Thats the only thing comes to my mind. It is similar to making an effective radio transmission for 50Hz requires very long antenna

Comment: You got it! So, that is the absolute main reason. Bulky, especially when it's the inductor made out of copper, is plain heavy, and expensive. It's certainly not impossible to build such a filter (but be careful what happens when you hit resonant frequency), but it consumes an undesireable amount of material if you need it to conduct much current. But you've figured that out yourself – congrats! If I were you: I'd take your exact comment, add it to the question (edit it), and ask whether there are *other* reasons!

Comment: Yes big but how big I dont know. Is the challenge marketing and selling or does it really require a filter as big as a camel for instance. Im not able to relate 10Henry to a size I mean. Or maybe when things get bigger power loss will be huge. But I dont know the main reason why on earth no one ever built it.

Comment: [This](https://www2.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Hammond-Manufacturing/158T?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsg%252by3WlYCkU%252bF2lzLeRQXMwKAWsI%252bGffc%3d) is a 1H inductivity. But it's only designed for 300 mA – if you wanted to filter, say, 10 A of AC current, yours would have to be 33 times as big, probably even bigger due to thermal problems. But it has an ohmic resistance of up to 40 Ω – totally unusable as line filter, so, that has to go down by a factor of at least 100. Meaning you need 100 times the size for resistance reasons. This thing weighs 583g. I'll let you do the math.

Comment: Too big to filter.))

Comment: To be completely fair, the inductivity you'd design for a line filter would be different (you actually would want that the inductivity has losses, whereas the inductivity I linked to is optimized to lose as little AC energy as possible), so it could be a bit smaller, but: The problem that you need more copper to conduct more current stays the same.

Comment: I've uploaded a picture of two different EMI filters. One of them is a two-stage (I've got them up to three-stage, which are bigger still.) [Have a look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK5Wt.png) Size, weight, and cost are just a few issues. If you want to isolate a system from a mains supply shared with a dental office running a 70 kV xray machine ... it gets significantly larger.

Comment: @Marcus is there a reason for saying "inductivity" rather than "inductance"? Not a crit - just an observation and a question.

Comment: Sure they build them - just go to the DC switchyard of a HVDC link and ask someone to point out the DC smoothing reactor - it's probably as big as a small truck and needs to be that way to prevent core saturation at the current used with the inductance required.

Comment: @Andyaka basically, being tired and not a native speaker :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller you do pretty good for a non native English speaker!

Comment: Thank you! Hope I'm doing fine as an engineer, too :)

Answer (score 4):

I designed a 100 Hz power line filter comprising a 300 mH choke, an 8 uF capacitor and some series resistance. The design worked on 60 Hz AC at 230 volts for a Canadian oil platform - it was used to prevent massive voltage spikes on the AC connection to a small private telephone exchange. The voltage spikes were just resetting the phone exchange every ten seconds and only occured when the machine that drove pipes into the oil well was operating.

> What makes it difficult or a challenge to design such filter with 200
>   Hz cut off for instance?

Well, I had to get an inductance of 300 mH and given that for a single turn the inductance was 10 uH, it meant I needed about 173 turns. This, stretched out end-to-end, was about 3 inches per turn or 43 foot of wire. So, to carry the bit of current to the phone exchange without too much volt drop I needed average sized connection wire of 7/0.2 (= 0.22 sq mm or about 24 AWG). If you do the math, the wire alone has the volume of a larger ferrite core so we are not talking suitable for a PCB because the core probably weighed around 300 grammes.

It soon mounts up but, the applications for this sort of filter are very few and far between unless you design HVDC switch yard reactor smoothing chokes: -

[image]

Note the choke is bottom left and compare this with the building middle right!